# Custom labels in tableviewcell

Tags: objective-c

Im trying to make a custom label instead of the standard textabel and detailtextlabel.

i've tried doing this by creating a label called "labelNumb", but it wont print it in the cells how come and how can i position this label in the cell?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{


    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }


    cell.userInteractionEnabled = NO;



    UILabel *labelNumb = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:labelNumb];
    labelNumb.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[scoreArray2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't set the frame for `labelNumb`.

Also, `if (cell == nil)` will never happen since `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:` is guaranteed to return a cell.

Also, this will mess up as you start scrolling, since you're adding a new UILabel every time, instead of reusing the existing one.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if `cell` is nil, and if it is create a new `UITableViewCell` with the same `identifier`.
2. Make a new frame, add the `UILabel` to it, and pass it in the
   `addSubview:` method.

Comment: `cell` will never be nil.